# Uncaught in promise error when trying to upload files

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

Everything works fine when preparing for upload and is logged to the console but once trying to upload , The Mongodb server stops working.

```
setPopup({

          open: true,

          severity: "success",

          message: response.data.message,

        });

      })

      .catch((err) => {

     console.log(err.response);

        setPopup({

          open: true,

          severity: "error",

          message: err.response.statusText,

        });

      });

  };
```

It brings an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError : cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusText')`

```
      .catch((err) => {

     console.log(err.response);

        setPopup({

          open: true,

          severity: "error",

          message: err.response.statusText,

        });

      });

  };
```

Am new to using backend so having troubles with database connectivity.

Comment: First of all just try to log statusText to check if it is undefined or present.

Comment: It states that it is undefined